# Label below and above jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, firefox

I have a `jquery-ui` slider. I want to display the exact value where the slider is just below the handle, while I want a "legend" over the slider.

I managed to display the value of the slider below the handle and to create the legend I've added a table above the slider, which displays very nicely in `Chrome`, but in `Firefox` the whole thing goes wrong.

[image: It doesn't look very nice.]

Here is my code (in [jade](http://jade-lang.com/))

```
    table.table(style='margin-bottom: 0px')
        tbody
            tr
                th
                    div
                        label(style='white-space:nowrap;margin-left: -40%') Totally Wrong
                th 
                    div
                        label(style="white-space:nowrap;") Neutral
                th
                    div
                        label(style='white-space:nowrap;margin-left: 80%') Totally OK
    div#slider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made these adjustments, but if anybody can give me a nicer answer I would really appreciate

```
 table.table(style='margin-bottom: 0px')
        tbody
            tr
                th(style='width:33%; text-align: center;')
                    div(style='white-space:nowrap;') 
                        label(style='margin-left: -100%') Totally Wrong
                th(style='width:33%; text-align: center;')
                    div(style='white-space:nowrap;') 
                        label Neutral
                th(style='width:33%; text-align: center;')
                    div(style='white-space:nowrap;') 
                        label(style='margin-left: 80%') Totally OK
```

Now in both browsers it looks the same.